# Computing pseudo-inverse of a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix-inverse, recipe

I'm looking to compute the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of a matrix in C++, can someone point me to a library implementation or a numerical recipe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 'Single Value Decomposition', from which you can find a C implementation [here](http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf/c2-6.pdf) from Numerical Recipes in C.

[This other site](https://planetmath.org/Pseudoinverse) describes how to use single value decomposition to calculate the pseudo-inverse.

Comment: numerical recipes implementation has licensing problems. I would suggest using LAPACK, which has an implementation of SVD (as well as a routine for the pseudo-inverse I guess)

Comment: The file from numerical recipes is password protected.

Comment: It did not used to be password protected. It's a bummer they changed that. :(

Comment: you can also use opencv (which actually uses LAPACK) to do the SVD (amont other things).

Comment: FYI, both links are broken.